# Auto login after registration PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I designed a web site that allows user to register with a simple html form. I want the user, after validating registration to be redirected to the home page and display this message for the new user "Account created" , I found many answers on the internet but all of them are old and different -that was confusing-  I would like to get the newest and the most efficient way to do this.

This is my log in code

```
 <?php // rnlogin.php
 include_once 'rnheader.php';
echo "<h3>Member Log in</h3>"; 
$error = $user = $pass = "";
if (isset($_POST['user'])) 
{
$user = sanitizeString($_POST['user']);
$pass = sanitizeString($_POST['pass']);
if ($user == "" || $pass == "")
    {
    $error = "Not all fields were entered<br />";
    }
    else
        {
        $query = "SELECT user,pass FROM rnmembers
            WHERE user='$user' AND pass='$pass'";
    if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql($query)) == 0)
        {
        $error = "Username/Password invalid<br />";
        }
        else
            {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
            die("You are now logged in. Please
                <a href='rnmembers.php?view=$user'>click here</a>.");
            }
            }
            }
 echo " <form method='post' action='rnlogin.php'>$error Username <input type='text' maxlength='16' name='user'
            value='$user' /><br /> Password <input type='password' maxlength='16' name='pass'
                value='$pass' /><br /> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <input type='submit' value='Login' /> </form>"
?>
```

and this is the code on my home page that create the session

```
include_once 'rnheader.php';
if (!isset($_SESSION['user']))
die("<br /><br />You must be logged in to view this page");
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
```

Comment: Please add code to your question.

Comment: I did but I think it is not improtant

Comment: It's important to know what you're using and how you're making things work at current, otherwise, you could get 50 different correct answers.

Comment: I edited the question with the log in code.

Comment: @Sparrow ... from my knowledge you're missing a session_start(); which must appear b4 using $_SESSION variables

and on the homepage you want ... just call session_start() and check those variables for values. If they are empty the user is not logged in , but if they have a value u can say Hello $_SESSION['user'];

Comment: Yes you are right I forget to mention it but I made it in my code, please see my code after editing I just mentioned the session code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do this the same way as doing the login.
You do the login by storing a $_cookie or $_session value with the user id.
So after registration just store the id and redirect them to the homepage.
On the homepage check for the cooke. If the cookie doesn't exist it means
the user isn't logged in and you should show a generic homepage.
If the user has the cookie set, use the userid to get the data about
him from the database and generate a page customized for that user.

Comment: I edited the question sir can you give more details sir?

Comment: I used it to explain it to him ... session are just a layer implemented over cookie. Personally I don't even use PHP much these days. And frameworks like CodeIgniter have their own session implementation

Comment: but that was more confusing than the answers that I found LOL

Comment: +1 to the CI reference! Best way to use PHP in my opinion. Although node.JS is taking over. But I have to disagree with the "layer over" statement. I've always used sessions as CI does, as a table in my database that stores current users' information and is *wiped* when a user logs out or after a check against it shows that user is past their expiration. I only use cookies (for about a decade now) to store simple page crap like; last selected tab, background color chosen, font size picked, blah blah blah.

Comment: @Sparrow first of all it's good to have a simple privary key in that SQL of yours. Like a number for each user , or you could just use the email as PK. Store that PK in a session variable ... read a little about sessions on PHP or W3Schools. On each page of the site you check that variable and you know which user is logged in.

it's a little like this on login:
`if(passowrd_typed_by_user ==  pass_from_db)`
`   $_SESSION['uid']= the value of the PK `
on every other page check the value of the PK. If it's null it means there's not logged in.

Comment: @SpYk3HH I'm a node.js devel mainly. My Bachelor Diploma Thesis is a MVC web server written from scratch on top of node.

Comment: @SpYk3HH The feel when I don't know PERL ... lol

Comment: Hi guys I am interested with your conversation but you got to help me :D I just edited my code with more details

Comment: @Sparrow ... in both cases you are missing the
session_start();
call before checking session variables

look here
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: Sorry for being late ,, look sir the session start is on the header.php :) this is not the problem

Comment: Oh , ok. Than when they register , just set the same Session variables and redirect them to he hompage
`$_SESSION['user'] = $user;`

`$_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;`

`header("Location: url_to_homepage");`
`die();`